# How to rename a Prerequisite

Tags: installation, installshield, prerequisites

I am new in installshield.I created a new Prerequisite, but I do not see where I can change the name so that when you run the install it does not show up as "**MySetupPrerequisite1**". how can I change this name so the user sees a better description of what Prerequisite are going to run?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to SetupPrerequisites foder, modify the name of MySetupPrerequisite1.prq

Comment: Note that the prerequisites are stored in the Installshield **Program Files** directory, not the Installshield **Project** directory. There is one shared database of prereqs that all Installshield projects share. On my current system, my prerequisites were in C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012\SetupPrerequisites\ .